# How can I dynamically change a number input's value?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a form with a input was `type="number"`, after submit I made it reset and backup in a list to resolve purpose.

If that any submit is failed, I want to resolve entire input. I also try convert innerHTML to Number before assign, but it not working. `Number.parseInt(document.querySelector("div#"+ item_Id +".result #context > #cmeasurement").innerHTML);`

I have that possible by change a number input's value?

```js
function resolveForm(item_Id) {
  document.querySelector("#addInventoryform #measurement").value = document.querySelector("div#" + item_Id + ".result #context > #cmeasurement").innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="addInventory_form">
  <form id="addInventoryform" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="measurment">Measurement</label>
    <input id="measurment" name="measurement" type="number" value="1">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="a123121" class="result" style="background-color: wheat">
  <div>
    <button onclick="resolveForm('a123121')" id="result_id">123121</button>
    <div id="status"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="context" style="display:none">
    <div id="cmeasurement">12312</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: FYI, nested ID selectors are usually unnecessary. IDs must be unique, so just use the interior one. The exception is when you're verifying that the outer element exists as part of the query.

Comment: A numeric input only accepts numbers. `innerHTML` returns a string.

Comment: Check your spelling: `measurement` (in your JS) != `measurment` (in your html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the input element in your HTML, you set your id="measurement".

In your function, you're calling your id as "measurment". If you fix your spelling, the function should work as expected.

See the snippet below:

```js
function resolveForm(item_Id) {
  document.querySelector("#addInventoryform #measurement").value = document.querySelector("div#" + item_Id + ".result #context > #cmeasurement").innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="addInventory_form">
  <form id="addInventoryform" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="measurment">Measurement</label>
    <input id="measurement" name="measurement" type="number" value="1">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="a123121" class="result" style="background-color: wheat">
  <div>
    <button onclick="resolveForm('a123121')" id="result_id">123121</button>
    <div id="status"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="context" style="display:none">
    <div id="cmeasurement">12312</div>
  </div>
</div>
```